# Listing filenames with restrictions with echo command in linux

Tags: linux

How to list all filenames starting with 'a' and containing exactly three characters with echo command. I tried:
echo a* ??? but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
echo a??
```

I think this should work as `?` matches just one character

Comment: Thanks also how would I list all filenames starting with 'a', but not 'aa'. Like  for example 'aaa' and 'aabb' must be excluded?